# mediaelement.js Fullscreen button pops out of line in firefox

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, mediaelement.js

Here's a link: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/dev/reels/documentary-drama-reel/

It's fine until you hit play, then the fullscreen button pops out of line and is positioned below player.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the solution in this post:
[How are controls sized in mediaelement.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504557/how-are-controls-sized-in-mediaelement-js)

You just have to turn the "autosizeProgress" off and size it the right way.